# HREFs Relative to Server Root

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, webserver

I have a bunch of HTML files exported from Next.js. All the HREFs are relative to the root of the web server (href="/static/..."). The links are broken if the application is deployed to a directory under the web server's root (http://server/app). Can this be controlled during the export from Next.js or corrected after the export?

Answer (score 0):

If is necessary to run the application in a subdirectory, the best thing to do is use basePath on next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/app',
}
```

Comment: I upgraded to v9.5.0 which is when basePath is available, but now I get "Property '_rewriteUrlForNextExport' dos not exist on type 'typeof Router'"